# error installing charlock_holmes gem on NitrousIO box

Tags: nitrousio

I need to install this gem for my rails app, but it complains its missing the libicu library. How can I get this gem to install on Nitrous.io ?

The output is below:

```
action@zzzxz:~$ gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... no
checking for main() in -licui18n... no


***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-icu-dir
    --without-icu-dir
    --with-icu-include
    --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
    --with-icu-lib
    --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `brew update` and then `brew install icu4c` and then tried to install the gem again it worked for me.